# Adding text output to Informix

Tags: informix

I have a server running Informix and have 2 questions about text output while code is running.

I have a file that contains the code

```
sperform rtl_est_dte
isql <g_rtl_mrg1.sql> test
isql <fm_prft.sql> test
isql <whs_prft.sql> test
isql <upgfp_frgt.sql> test
isql <upd_plants.sql> test
```

Is there a way to add text output between each sql on the output screen so I can tell which step it is on?

OR

Can I add text into the actual SQL coding for each stage that would show in the output when running? Right now all I see is "Selected Database" "Deleted 424 rows" etc. I know how to add hidden text with `{ … }` but not how to display text.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a shell script.  It would be clearer if it started with a shebang and some comments:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Run rtl_est_dte form to get new data,
# then run 5 scripts to process the data, saving the results in file test
```

Anyway, given that it is probably a shell script, you should be able to add `echo` lines to annotate what you want:

```
sperform rtl_est_dte
echo "Running g_rtl_mrg1"
isql <g_rtl_mrg1.sql> test
echo "Running fm_prft"
isql <fm_prft.sql> test
echo "Running whs_prft"
isql <whs_prft.sql> test
echo "Running upgfp_frgt"
isql <upgfp_frgt.sql> test
echo "Running upd_plants"
isql <upd_plants.sql> test
echo "Finished"
```

I hope you'll be able to give more meaningful names to the steps being run, but that illustrates what you could do.

I also observe that it keeps on zapping the `test` file, so the information saved by running `g_rtl_mrg1.sql` is lost when `fm_prft.sql` is run, and that's lost when `whs_prft.sql` is run, and so on.  Use `>>` to append to the `test` file.  It would be more conventional to separate the output redirection from the input redirection:

```
isql <upd_plants.sql >>test
```

rather than the current:

```
isql <upd_plants.sql> test
```

That isn't anything remotely like XML.  Still, at least the original author didn't use:

```
<upd_plant.sql> test isql
```

That works the same — it confuses everyone who reads it.

You can also embed shell escapes in the `.sql` files:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeWhere;

!echo "Hello world!"

SELECT * FROM ElseWhere;
```

IIRC, the shell escapes don't work if you try to read the `.sql` file in the `isql` SQL Editor and then run it.  It only works from the command line as in the code in the question.

The progress output (`Database selected` etc) is written to standard error, for better or worse (worse, IMO, but I wrote my own SQLCMD years before Microsoft produced theirs, precisely because I didn't like what `isql` did, nor what `dbaccess` did after it was released).

Comment: To have the SQL script output arbitrary text you can add a statement of the form:

SELECT "arbitrary text" FROM systables WHERE tabid=1;